# I installed latest version of ruby and jekyll and there is an error jekyll serve error

Tags: arrays, regex, rubygems, jekyll

Jekyll latest version and still error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow community. Please read this [*how to*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to update your question and before asking any further ones.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Jekyll (v3.2.1) should be run through Bundler.

Run install first and after changing gem dependencies:

```
bundle install
```

Then run Jekyll normally, but prefix with `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```